# What about Christians making truthful accusations "railing" for the good/benefit of the hearer(s)?

Tags: word-study

> **1 Peter 3:9** Not rendering evil for evil, or railing for railing: but contrariwise blessing; knowing that ye are thereunto called, that ye should inherit a blessing.

> **2 Peter 2:11** Whereas angels, which are greater in power and might, bring not railing accusation against them before the Lord.

> **Jude 1:9** Yet Michael the archangel, when contending with the devil he disputed about the body of Moses, durst not bring against him a railing accusation, but said, The Lord rebuke thee.

Do these scriptures/statements Forbid (preclude, prohibit, rule out, condemn) Christians from bringing forth any accusation(s) at all against others even when the accusation is clearly, verifiably true? or is the word "railing" the definitive qualifier?

In other words, does the word "railing" imply and prohibit only untrue, false, unverifiable accusations, falsely maligning accusations?

For example, if a person (even those in authority: including Political Leaders) commits a crime/a sin/lies, etc. which is true & verifiable and is harmful to others, do these scriptures prohibit us (Christians) from "bringing forth" (speaking of, accusing, etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

"Railing" is found in the King James Bible which was published in the year 1611. "Not rendering evil for evil, or railing for railing". KJB 1 Peter 3:9

More modern versions put:

Good News, "cursing with cursing".

Weymouth N.T. "abuse with abuse".

World English Bible; Chritian Standard Bible and NASB 1977 all put "insult for insult".

The plain meaning of "cursing with cursing" is, if someone curses you, that is not a reason to reply with a curse.

In your question you use the word "accusation". No version that I can find uses this word.

I have no idea if in 1611 the word "railing" meant "accusation". But all the modern versions are clear. "abuse", "insult" and "cursing" go beyond "assessing/judging" someone, and introduce "condemnation".

Example of assessing: "I think Jim makes great cakes, but in my view he is not gifted to lead Sunday School".

We may assess/judge; but we are not called upon to condemn/curse.

Only God can condemn because:

A. All authority has been given to Jesus. Matthew 28:18

B. "For He knows the secrets of the heart". Psalm 44:21.

Answer (score 0):

Do these scriptures/statements Forbid (preclude, prohibit, rule out, condemn) Christians from bringing forth any accusation(s) at all against others even when the accusation is clearly, verifiably true?

No, on the contrary, Matthew 18:

> 15“If your brother or sister sins, go and **point out their fault**, just between the two of you. If they listen to you, you have won them over. 16But if they will not listen, take one or two others along, so that ‘every matter may be established by the testimony of two or three witnesses.’ 17If they still refuse to listen, tell it to the church; and if they refuse to listen even to the church, treat them as you would a pagan or a tax collector.

OP: Is the word "railing" the definitive qualifier?
In other words, does the word "railing" imply and prohibit only untrue, false, unverifiable accusations, falsely maligning accusations?

I'd recommend reading several versions to get a better sense of the original Greek meaning. See Stroud's answer.

OP: For example, if a person (even those in authority: including Political Leaders) commits a crime/a sin/lies, etc. which is true & verifiable and is harmful to others, do these scriptures prohibit us (Christians) from "bringing forth" (speaking of, accusing, etc.)?

As Christians, we obey a higher law, Acts 5:

> 27 The apostles were brought in and made to appear before the **Sanhedrin** to be questioned by the high priest. 28 “We gave you strict orders not to teach in this name,” he said. “Yet you have filled Jerusalem with your teaching and are determined to make us guilty of this man’s blood.”
>
> 29 Peter and the other apostles replied: “**We must obey God rather than human beings!**